# I am trying to return the complete list of nested document after $unwind

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Please forgive my brevity, I am new to MongoDB aggregate framework. I have the following collection with "history" as a nested document and I am trying to project the matching collection together with the full list of history but my query is only returning the matched element in the nested history.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc75fbcd1de1e96e0925a7e"),
    "case_id" : "5002J00001E2JheQAF",
    "__v" : 0,
    "account_id" : "0015000000xxYAWAA2",
    "account_name" : "HelloWorld",
    "caseNumber" : "C1000013634",
    "caseOrigin" : "Email",
    "case_type" : "A-Partner",
    "create_date" : ISODate("2019-04-29T20:15:48.000Z"),
    "current_mrr" : null,
    "escalated_team" : null,
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cdad34e4520d570fc0f6a85"),
            "history_id" : "0172J0000tXXzkuQAD",
            "field" : "created",
            "new_value" : null,
            "old_value" : null,
            "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-29T20:15:52.000Z"),
            "created_by_id" : "005500000071WBzAAM"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cdad34e4520d570fc0f6a84"),
            "history_id" : "0172J0000tXXzkyQAD",
            "field" : "Provider_Group__c",
            "new_value" : "HelloWorld Provisioning",
            "old_value" : "SGS - Web and Chat",
            "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-29T20:15:52.000Z"),
            "created_by_id" : "005500000071WBzAAM"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cdad34e4520d570fc0f6a7d"),
            "history_id" : "0172J0000tYzZgoQAF",
            "field" : "Status",
            "new_value" : "In Progress",
            "old_value" : "Pending Customer Response",
            "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-30T13:38:38.000Z"),
            "created_by_id" : "005500000071WBzAAM"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cdad34e4520d570fc0f6a7b"),
            "history_id" : "0172J0000tYzbgJQAR",
            "field" : "Status",
            "new_value" : "Resolved",
            "old_value" : "In Progress",
            "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-30T13:54:44.000Z"),
            "created_by_id" : "0052J000007nM11QAE"
        }
    ],
  "feeds" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cdad34e4520d570fc0f6a78"),
            "feed_id" : "0D52J00006qBd5PSAS",
            "event" : "TextPost",
            "created_by_id" : "0052J000007nM11QAE",
            "visibility" : "InternalUsers",
            "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-30T13:54:42.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cdad34e4520d570fc0f6a77"),
            "feed_id" : "0D52J00006qBd4kSAC",
            "event" : "EmailMessageEvent",
            "created_by_id" : "0052J000007nM11QAE",
            "visibility" : "InternalUsers",
            "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-30T13:54:32.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cdad34e4520d570fc0f6a76"),
            "feed_id" : "0D52J00006qBc4GSAS",
            "event" : "EmailMessageEvent",
            "created_by_id" : "005500000071WBzAAM",
            "visibility" : "InternalUsers",
            "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-30T13:38:34.000Z")
        }
    ],
    "issue_level" : "HelloWorld",
    "last_month_service_mrr" : 572.866,
    "last_update" : ISODate("2019-05-14T14:00:39.000Z"),
    "owner" : "Ajay AJAY",
    "owner_id" : "0052J000007nM11QAE",
    "product" : "Virtual World",
    "provider_group" : "HelloWorld Provisioning",
    "provider_group_manager" : null,
    "provider_group_manager_email" : null,
    "resolve_date" : ISODate("2019-04-30T13:54:42.000Z"),
    "rt" : null,
    "service_mrr" : 583,
    "severity" : null,
    "status" : "Closed",
    "subject" : "HelloWorld - The Complex - 7516664 - Unsuspend",
    "support_country" : null,
    "support_group" : "Support - ETS"
}
```

Here is my query

```
db.getCollection('cases').aggregate([
{ 
     $match: {
          "history.created_date": { 
               '$gte': new Date("2019-04-01T00:00:00"),
               '$lte': new Date("2019-04-30T23:59:59") 
          }
     }
},
{ 
    "$unwind": "$history"
}
,{
    "$match": {
        "history.created_date":{
               '$gte': new Date("2019-04-01T00:00:00"),
               '$lte': new Date("2019-04-30T23:59:59")
        },
        "$or" :[{"history.new_value":{
            "$in":['Tier 2','Global Application Support Team','HelloWorld Provisioning'],
        }},{
            "history.field" : "Resolved"
        }],

        "history.old_value":{
            "$nin":['HelloWorld Provisioning','Global Application Support Team'],
        },
     }
}
,{
     $group: {
          "_id": {
              year: {
                  $year: "$history.created_date"
              },
              month: {
                  $month: "$history.created_date"
              },
              week: {
                  $week: "$history.created_date"
              }
          },
          cases: {
                        $push: {
                            caseNumber: "$caseNumber",
                            account_name: "$account_name",
                            status: "$status",
                            owner: "$owner",
                            owner_id: "$owner_id",
                            create_date: "$create_date",
                            last_update: "$last_update",
                            resolve_date: "$resolve_date",
                            provider_group: "$provider_group",
                            issue_level: "$issue_level",
                            case_type: "$case_type",
                            account_id: "$account_id",
                            history: "$history",
                            feeds: "$feeds",
                            product: "$product",
                            severity: "$severity",
                            support_group: "$support_group"
                        }
                    }
     }
},{
                $project: {
                    "dates": "$_id",
                    _id: 0,
                    "cases": "$cases"
                }
            },
            {$sort: {_id: 1}}
])

The result i get is the matched element of the flattened array.

{
    "dates" : {
        "year" : 2019,
        "month" : 4,
        "week" : 14
    },
    "totalCases" : 86.0,
    "cases" : [ 
        {
            "caseNumber" : "C1781724",
            "account_name" : "American Fed of Govt Emp",
            "status" : "Closed",
            "owner" : "Hy Van",
            "owner_id" : "005500000071TgPAAU",
            "create_date" : ISODate("2019-04-10T22:32:40.000Z"),
            "last_update" : ISODate("2019-04-29T18:45:42.000Z"),
            "resolve_date" : ISODate("2019-04-15T18:34:50.000Z"),
            "provider_group" : "Tier 2",
            "issue_level" : "Phone Service",
            "case_type" : "Issue-Fault",
            "account_id" : "001500000168SrjAAE",
            "history" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5cc75fcd55e11149c3366285"),
                "history_id" : "0172J0000t73NlXQAU",
                "field" : "Provider_Group__c",
                "new_value" : "Tier 2",
                "old_value" : "SGS - Web and Chat",
                "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-11T19:10:22.000Z"),
                "created_by_id" : "005500000071TgXAAU"
            },
            "feeds" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc75fcd55e11149c336627a"),
                    "feed_id" : "0D52J00006omQnySAE",
                    "event" : "EmailMessageEvent",
                    "created_by_id" : "005500000071TgPAAU",
                    "visibility" : "InternalUsers",
                    "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-15T18:34:52.000Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc75fcd55e11149c3366279"),
                    "feed_id" : "0D52J00006omQnxSAE",
                    "event" : "TextPost",
                    "created_by_id" : "005500000071TgPAAU",
                    "visibility" : "InternalUsers",
                    "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-15T18:34:50.000Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc75fcd55e11149c3366278"),
                    "feed_id" : "0D52J00006oGTMwSAO",
                    "event" : "EmailMessageEvent",
                    "created_by_id" : "005500000071WBzAAM",
                    "visibility" : "AllUsers",
                    "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-12T16:15:47.000Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc75fcd55e11149c3366277"),
                    "feed_id" : "0D52J00006oGQhvSAG",
                    "event" : "TextPost",
                    "created_by_id" : "00550000007gdQEAAY",
                    "visibility" : "InternalUsers",
                    "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-12T15:47:26.000Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc75fcd55e11149c3366276"),
                    "feed_id" : "0D52J00006oGQXTSA4",
                    "event" : "TextPost",
                    "created_by_id" : "00550000007gdQEAAY",
                    "visibility" : "InternalUsers",
                    "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-12T15:45:30.000Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc75fcd55e11149c3366275"),
                    "feed_id" : "0D52J00006oER2gSAG",
                    "event" : "EmailMessageEvent",
                    "created_by_id" : "0052J0000082whRQAQ",
                    "visibility" : "AllUsers",
                    "created_date" : ISODate("2019-04-10T22:32:42.000Z")
                }
            ],
            "product" : "Virtual Office",
            "severity" : null,
            "support_group" : "Support - SMB"
        },
        .
        .
        .
}
```

What can I do to return the full list of history?

Comment: Not sure I understand what it is that you are trying to do.  If you want all of the history of a matching document, it does not make sense to unwind, then filter out histories with the $match.  Did you unwind so that the match conditions are all of the same history?  If this is the case, instead use [elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/).  Please clarify so that an answer can be provided.

Comment: @jcarter, using elemMatch does not give me the benefit of grouping the data as 
 I want. My intention is to return all of the history of the matched document but I figured it wasn't possible as you have rightly pointed out so I choose a different approach. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My query was okay for what I wanted to achieve but it didn't return the full list of histories for the matched document. The only way was to make a second query to retrieve the full document using the cases returned.

```
db.getCollection('cases').aggregate([
{ 
     $match: {
          "history.created_date": { 
               '$gte': new Date("2019-04-01T00:00:00"),
               '$lte': new Date("2019-04-30T23:59:59") 
          }
     }
},
{ 
    "$unwind": "$history"
}
,{
    "$match": {
        "history.created_date":{
               '$gte': new Date("2019-04-01T00:00:00"),
               '$lte': new Date("2019-04-30T23:59:59")
        },
        "$or" :[{"history.new_value":{
            "$in":['Tier 2','Global Application Support Team','HelloWorld Provisioning'],
        }},{
            "history.field" : "Resolved"
        }],

        "history.old_value":{
            "$nin":['HelloWorld Provisioning','Global Application Support Team'],
        },
     }
}
,{
     $group: {
          "_id": {
              year: {
                  $year: "$history.created_date"
              },
              month: {
                  $month: "$history.created_date"
              },
              week: {
                  $week: "$history.created_date"
              }
          },
          cases:  {$addToSet: "$caseNumber"}
     }
},{
                $project: {
                    "dates": "$_id",
                    _id: 0,
                    "cases": "$cases"
                }
            },
            {$sort: {_id: 1}}
])
```